# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter Exception

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this JS :

```
if (typeof window.bankSelector !== 'undefined') {
    if (window.bankSelector.val() <= 0)
        window.branchSelector.prop("disabled", true);
    else {
        var bankId = window.Selector.val();
        $.getJSON(window.baseUrl + "/asyncapi/MyFunc", { bankId: bankId},
               function (data) {
                   window.branchSelector.empty();
                   window.branchSelector.append($('<option/>', {
                       value: 0,
                       text: '- nothing -'
                   }));
                   $.when($.each(data, function (index, item) {
                       window.branchSelector.append($('<option/>', {
                           value: item.Value,
                           text: item.Text
                       }));
                   })).then(function () {
                       window.branchSelector.select{
                           minimumResultsForSearch: 10
                       });
                       if (window.branchId > 0)
                           window.branchId.select('val', window.branchId);
                   });
               });
    }
```

And I have this C# code :

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public async Task<JsonResult> MyFunc(int bankId)
    {
        var branchlist=
            await _db.Branches.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(
                    m =>
                        m.Companies.Any(y => y.CompanyId== ((CustomPrincipal)User).CompanyId) &&
                        m.Bank.BankId == bankId).Select(m => new
                        {
                            m.BranchName
                        }).ToListAsync();

        var son = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var branches = branchlist.OrderBy(m => m.branchname).Select(m => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = m.branchName+ @" - " + m.SubeKodu,
                Value = m.BranchId.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
            });
            return branches;
        });
        return Json(son, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And I get this :

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'bankid'
>   of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult]
>   MyFunc(Int32)' in 'MySolution.Controllers.AsyncApiController'. An
>   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

I'm really lost in this error. I don't know what to do. Can you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: try : ``bankId: bankId``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It's not the actual error. I mistakenly wrote that part.

Answer (score 4):

Your c# method did not receive the `bankId` parameter and thus used `null`by default, which is not compatible with the expected type `int`(not nullable).

It seems it's because you put `bankID` instead of `bankId` in this line:

```
$.getJSON(window.baseUrl + "/asyncapi/MyFunc", { bankID: bankId},
                                                 ^^^^^^
```

### Update

This line has a typo too:

```
var bankaId = window.Selector.val();
        ^
```

Another lead: are you sure this variable does not hold `null` as the value?

Comment: I mistakenly wrote that part, it's not the actual error.  But thanks anyway

Comment: @jason so you changed to `bankId` and still get the same message?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm still getting the same message.